# Unity doesn't load 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, unity, dell, startup

***I think a new thread is justified, as most of the solutions on the old thread: ([Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)) that worked with previous versions of Ubuntu didn't work on 16.04 LTS***

My original problem:

I'm new to Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) just installed it a month ago on a Dell Inspiron 15R SE laptop. So far it's been working fine apart from the dedicated graphics (MD Radeon HD 7730M) but it's a well known problem, thought I'll sort it later.

When I tried to start up today the problem described in the title occurred. No toolbars on the top right or the left, nothing, apart from a pop-up window of a cleanup application (Bleach Bit) I've installed that always pops up at startup. That window has the top control bar missing though and can't even grab and move it.

While checking what's actually left that works, still managed to open firefox to send this post via an unconventional route: right click/change desktop background/all settings/Details/legal notice/clicking a blue highlighted link on that notice that opened firefox :D Also: logging on to the guest account everything worked just fine. *These discoveries proved to be very useful as I could at least seek for solutions online from my laptop, without having to use another pc.

Has anybody experienced similar, knows the solution or can direct my steps how to find it out please? I'm a bit desperate as most of my life/work done on my laptop, so it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers! :(

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention in the OP that could possibly have something to do with it. Last time the laptop still worked I used a new wireless adapter the first time (TP-LINK TL-WN722N). I didn't have to tamper with anything, it worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent an entire day probing various possible solutions from the old thread with no success, here is the solution(s) that worked for me:

I did the following two things, then reboot($ sudo reboot):

1/@julianromera's solution referred to an Ubuntu open bug. More info:bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1285444
His command line was:$ mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old

2/@Fullbuffer's solution on another forum was moving the ~/.cache directory out of the way and restart.
His command line was:$ mv ~/.cache ~/.cache-NOGOOD

I did these two things then rebooted with ($ sudo reboot) and now I'm up and running.

Hope this will help someone! One advise: do not despair! If I managed to solve it then anybody can :)